# Converting an Array into object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to know the best way to convert an array in Js to object.

This is the sample of what i want to do.
Input => ['abc', 'def'];
Output => { abc: true, def: true }

I have done it using the code below. But just wanted to know if

```
**function toObject(strings) {
    var rv = {}
    strings.forEach(string => {
        rv[string] = true
    })
  return rv
}**
```

This function serves the purpose. But any experts out there with a best and efficient way possible.

Comment: `strings.reduce( (a,c) => (a[c]=true, a), {})`

Comment: Your function itself is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by *best and efficient way possible*, since yours is **alright** according to me, this is a less versbose version

```
var output = strings.reduce( (a,c) => (a[c]=true, a), {})
```

**Demo**

```js
var strings = ['abc', 'def'];
var output = strings.reduce( (a,c) => (a[c]=true, a), {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: "a[c]=true" - I understood this part. But can you please explain me the second part - ",a". All in all i want to know what this second parameter is doing after comma (a[c]=true, a). Is this assigning value in a.

Comment: That is the value returned by expression in () braces as output of every iteration. Please read up about reduce

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now i understood it completely.

Answer (score 1):

You could map single objects and assign it to the same object.

```js
var array = ['abc', 'def'],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(key => ({ [key]: true })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Nice, didn't thought of using Object.assign myself +1

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I also didn't gave a thought for this.